# How do I parse these book titles with ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I want ruby to read the titles of all books in my books collection that currently looks like this:

```
No.Starch.The.Book.of.Ruby.Jun.2011.mobi
No.Starch.The.Book.of.Ruby.Jun.2011.pdf
Oreilly.Graphics.and.Animation.on.iOS.Apr.2011.epub
Oreilly.Graphics.and.Animation.on.iOS.Apr.2011.pdf
Packtpub.Core.Data.iOS.Essentials.Apr.2011.pdf
Pragmatic.iOS.Recipes.Jul.2011.epub
```

First thing I want to do is parse out the publisher names. I got myself started here: http://rubular.com/r/muioQM1Gsq

But how exactly do I parse multiple publisher strings? I am a noob at this really - could somone please help?

Comment: Why was this marked down? What did I do wrong?

Comment: I have tried matching one name. I want to know how to collect an array of publisher names. http://rubular.com/r/muioQM1Gsq

Comment: If you don't show the code, then how the community will understand what you have tried?

Comment: @AmitErandole unless you hard code each publisher and book name each time you match,the data in its current state is not properly organized.it's hard to differentiate between publisher name and book name..had the publisher name and book name been separated by space or some other char then it would be suitable to use `regex`..the data in the current state cannot be parsed with regex..blame it on the format of the data..

Comment: You can try `(?<=^|\n)(No\.Starch\.)`

Comment: @AmitErandole, the site is about programming, so your application-domain question is partly off-topic. You need to try something and distill your question down to an actual programming problem. As an example, the question "How do I make more money?" is arguably quite reasonable and perhaps extremely important to just about everyone. But, it's off-topic for this site. One safe way to ask a question here is to say: *I have this* (provide example) *input, I want this* (example) *output, and I've tried this* (example code).

Comment: I didn't ask How to make more money - I asked how to solve a regex problem and I stated that I expected the publisher names to be returned in the parsing match. - I showed the code I had in the rubular link - perhaps the link didn't work?

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ I can hard code the values in the regex because I have a limited list of publishers

Comment: Don't put code or regex on other sites and expect people helping you to go there. We work for free using our spare time and jumping to other sites wastes it. And, if the link breaks your question becomes worthless.

Comment: @theTinMan Ok - good point. I had an issue once where SO moderator told me I had put too much code. Will use better judgement next time

Comment: Put in enough to demonstrate the problem, and no more. Supply enough data to show the various cases you expect to encounter. Describe the problem so we know of any special conditions that rule out certain types of answers.

Comment: ok - good advice. Thank you for your help - learning a lot from your answer today. I didn't even know what `DATA` was

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a basic example how I'd do it:

```
TITLE_HASH = {
  'No.Starch' => 'No_Starch'
}
TITLE_REGEX = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(TITLE_HASH.keys).source })\b/i

DATA.each do |fn|
  puts fn.gsub(TITLE_REGEX, TITLE_HASH).split('.').first.tr('_', ' ')
end

__END__
No.Starch.The.Book.of.Ruby.Jun.2011.mobi
No.Starch.The.Book.of.Ruby.Jun.2011.pdf
Oreilly.Graphics.and.Animation.on.iOS.Apr.2011.epub
Oreilly.Graphics.and.Animation.on.iOS.Apr.2011.pdf
Packtpub.Core.Data.iOS.Essentials.Apr.2011.pdf
Pragmatic.iOS.Recipes.Jul.2011.epub
```

Which outputs this when run:

```
No Starch
No Starch
Oreilly
Oreilly
Packtpub
Pragmatic
```

Maintain `TITLE_HASH` with the publisher's patterns, replacing the delimiting `.` with '_' for any names that are longer than one word.

This solution requires maintenance by hand, but that's because there's no way to isolate the publisher information; Sometimes it's the first words, sometimes the first two, and I'm sure there could be even more words.

Comment: Pragmatic seems to be part of the title, the file name doesn't seem to have a title here.

Comment: In general, it is best to keep a set of publisher, then pick out the publisher from the name (if any), then pick out the date. The rest is the book title.

Comment: Pragmatic is the name of the publishing company. http://pragprog.com/book/cdirec/ios-recipes

Comment: Lol, this is one good example of the need for domain knowledge...

Comment: I have a limited set of publisher names that actually follow the same format around 8 -10.

Comment: One reason I use a separate hash to contain the `"publisher.name" => "publisher_name"` mapping is to make it easier to maintain. That hash could be moved to a YAML file, making it easy to update without messing with the code. YAML is a very easy to read format that is great for data files used to initialize programs. With only 8-10 it's not a big deal, but for other purposes it can be important.

Comment: @theTinMan - trying out your code bit by bit on irb to understand how exactly you are doing this. What exactly is the `source` method?

Comment: I understood the YAML file point btw - will try that out once I understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: "`What exactly is the source method?`" Look up [Regexp.source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-source).